# jquery: How to stop html anchors moving the document?

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

I have about 40 links which are all handled within jquery but when they are clicked it moves the page position to the top. Is there a better way to stop this happening without giving each one an event handler then doing `e.preventDefault()` ? Even if I could just include it in the function that is executed without doing `return false` as that never seems to work for me.

Comment: Do their `href` attribute point to `#` ?

Comment: yh they're all handled with jquery so it just links to #

Comment: Links shouldn't point to `#`. They should point to a valid URI, or not be links at all.

Comment: but its done on the same page??

Comment: Is there a reason you want these things to be links rather than some other element without the annoying default behaviour?

Comment: yea just use a `p` (or whatever) and css `{cursor:pointer}` to indicate its something to click, and put the click event on that

Comment: yh haha just seeing if there was some way to do it before changing all my pages didnt think of it before i started

Comment: or you can use `href="javascript:;"` I think, although its a little ugly

Comment: I'd use a `button` element. It has the closest semantic meaning to what you'd generally want, plus all the built in browser behaviour (such as navigating and triggering with the keyboard).

Comment: navigating and triggering with the keyboard ? like pressing tab to get to it or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than applying `e.preventDefault` to each one individually, you can apply it to them all in one function by using jQuery's powerful matching features.

This code will match all `<a>` tags with their `href` attribute set to `#`.

```
$("a[href='#']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```